# Can we run one thread group by remote machine while another thread group by local host in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have two thread groups , and requirement is that I have to run first thread group by remote machines(distributed testing) using the JMeter option "remote start all" , while second thread group has to be run by only one machine or only by localhost using option "start".
Please suggest how do I achieve such scenario in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

As all remote slaves are executing the same script I would go for the following approach:

1. Put all the requests in 1st and 2nd Thread Groups under the [If Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)
2. Use conditions which return hostname or IP address ([__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) and [__machineIP](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions correspondingly) like:

   `"${__machineIP()}" == "10.10.10.1"`

[image: If Controller]

This way If Controller's children will be executed only if hostname or IP address matches what's provided in "Condition"

By the way, JMeter master doesn't execute test, it only sends test script to slaves and collects results.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri , it worked .We can also use master as a load injector.

Comment: Request will not run under the if controller but both thread groups will inject the load which consequently will utilize the resources.